# JQuery Trigger Event on Dynamically added elements programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I can successfully bind an event to dynamically added elements, but I have a problem triggering it on its first load programmatically.

```
$('body').on('change', '#elem', function () {
    console.log('bind event success');
});
```

I tried these codes below but do not work.

Not working

```
$('body').trigger('change');
```

Not working

```
$('body').on('change', '#elem', function () {
    console.log('hello world');
}).change();
```

Comment: [$('#elem').trigger("change")](https://jsfiddle.net/4xfy7e5r/)

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event on the DOM element `#elem` directly, as you can see here:

```js
$('body').on('change', '#elem', function () {
    console.log('new value is: '+this.value);
});

$("button").click(function(){$("#elem").val("3").change()})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="elem"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>

<button>trigger change to 3</button>
```